# How can I hide this table row based on the value of an input field 4 levels down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

- I have a table with lots of rows
- I have a filter to hide these rows based on the content of a child element (an input field) several levels down within the row

The input field within the row is wrapped several times. I can't manage to hide the row based on that inputs value.

Here's how a row looks:

```
<tr class="acf-row" data-id="row-13">
    <td class="acf-field acf-field-date-picker acf-field-5de02ec006a2e" data-name="datum" data-type="date_picker" data-key="field_5de02ec006a2e">
        <div class="acf-input">
             <div class="acf-date-picker acf-input-wrap" data-date_format="dd.mm.yy" data-first_day="1">
                  <input type="text" class="input hasDatepicker" value="24.03.2020" id="dp1582735317447">                     
             </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Please note that there are more siblings on each level than I've put in here for readability. But the hierarchy is as displayed here.

Then I've got this input field to define what we want to filter:

```
<input placeholder="Datum filtern" type="text" id="datefilter" style="padding:5px; width:150px;">
```

And last but not least the jquery:

```
$( "#datefilter" ).change(function() {  

    var filterdate = $("#datefilter").val();

    jQuery('.input.hasDatepicker').each(function() {
        var currentElement = $(this);
        var dateinfield = currentElement.val();

        if( dateinfield !== filterdate){            
                    $(this).closest('.acf-row').hide();                     
        }           
    });     
});
```

Currently it hides all the rows, not just those with a different value. What should happen is that only the rows get hidden where the value of #datefilter is different from the value of .input.hasDatepicker

I tried a few things like trying to use .parent().parent()... but didn't get it to work. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a jsfiddle with the whole table including all siblings:
https://jsfiddle.net/59by3w7o/

UPDATE:
I think I can now say for sure the issue is 2 instances of the input element in each row. Here's a jsfiddle with only that and no noise:

https://jsfiddle.net/8k41xy6u/

How could I solve that? I tried playing with :first but couldn't get it to take the first within each .acf-row and not the very first in the whole document.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, and a (simplified) version in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/znxsky6g/) works as expected.  You'll of course need to re-display everything every time `#datefilter` changes as well, to make sure things hidden by a previous filter don't stay hidden.  I've added that.  I also replaced your use of `jQuery` with `$`, to be consistent.  Lastly you should really cache your selectors, so jQuery doesn't have to parse the whole DOM each time.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I appreciate it. I've just made a fiddle based on yours where I put the whole beast of a table in - and same as on my machine - it now hides all the rows. Can you maybe see why it does that?

https://jsfiddle.net/59by3w7o/

--

Edit: Could the problem have to do with there being a second instance of .input.hasDatepicker in the same row? If so, any idea how to rewrite my script?

Comment: I think I can now say for sure the issue is 2 instances of the input element. Here's a jsfiddle with only that and no noise: https://jsfiddle.net/8k41xy6u/
How could I solve that? I tried playing with :first but couldn't get it to take the first within each .acf-row and not the very first in the whole document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8k41xy6u/), a table row looks something like:

```
<tr class="acf-row">
    <td>
        <div class="acf-input">
            <div>
                <input class="input hasDatepicker" type="text" value="26.03.2020">
                <input class="input hasDatepicker" type="text" value="10:00">
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And now the problem becomes clear.  In the JS, `.each()` iterates over *everything* with the classes `.input` and `.hasDatepicker`.  Both your inputs match that, so it will test both of them.  If the value of the either one does not match your `filterdate` that row will be hidden.  But the 2nd input value is a time, and that will never match a date, no matter what the date is - so every row will always be hidden.

There are 2 obvious ways to tackle this - 1) make the inputs distinguishable, so you can target just the date input in your filter comparison, *OR* 2) somehow target just the first input in the set of 2.

The first option (make them distinguishable) is by far the best, as the second relies on the layout of the HTML.  It could happen in future that you'll do a redesign and the inputs won't be in the same order, or even in the same `<div>`, and then your JS will break.  That might even happen without you doing it or even knowing about it if the HTML is autogenerated by some 3rd-party library (eg ACF/Wordpress), and a plugin update changes things.  But if you can distinguish the inputs then you can target the right ones no matter where they are on the page.

To make them distinguishable, you could add a class, eg:

```
<input class="input hasDatepicker date" type="text" value="26.03.2020">
```

Then update your JS to target only those:

```
$('.input.hasDatepicker.date').each(function(i) {
```

If changing the HTML isn't an option, then you'll have to rely on and make use of position.  Iterate instead over all `div.acf-input`s, and find the first input in each:

```
$('div.acf-input').each(function(i) {
    var dateinfield = $(this).find('input.input.hasDatepicker').first().val();
    // ...
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/f5m3whaz/) (of option 2).

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks man!

Changing the html is tricky as it comes from a wordpress plugin and I'd prefer not to temper with that plugins source for updating reasons. So I will be using your second solution.